# Bluetooth not working with Ralink RT3290

Tags: wifi, drivers, bluetooth, networking, hp

Just got a WiFi adapter for my laptop and WiFi is working correctly in elementary OS.But Bluetooth is not showing and shows as if there are no Bluetooth adapters installed.

Output of `sudo lshw -c network` :

```
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan1
       version: 00
       serial: b8:76:3f:53:8f:99
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=3.19.0-59-generic firmware=0.37 ip=192.168.1.3 latency=0 link=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:16 memory:f0210000-f021ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 05
       serial: 84:34:97:89:f6:4e
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:36 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f0004000-f0004fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff
```

Comment: What computer model do you have?

Comment: HP Pavilion g7 2269wm

Answer (score 2):

According to this site, HP Pavilion g7-2268wm does not have Bluetooth

http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03487531

I even checked the Windows drivers for the machine and couldn't find anything.

http://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/HP-Pavilion-g7-Notebook-PC-series/5296086/model/5312246

[This post](https://askubuntu.com/a/767274/414234) claims that you need Kernel 4.4.0 (Xenial) in order to see your bluetooth card. Freya runs on kernel 3.19, if you want to upgrade run this command.

> sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-xenial
>   xserver-xorg-core-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-lts-xenial
>   xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-xenial
>   libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-xenial

Once you're done restart your machine and try again.

Comment: I put the RT3290 WiFi + Bluetooth card in it

Comment: Did you upgrade the kernel?

Comment: I will try.Currently I am running out of space on /boot for that.And I think it also might break FGLRX so should I use 4.1 instead

Answer (score 1):

My friend, there is NO SOLUTIONS to get this particular module (rtbth) work. This is a old-bug problem, with tons of how-to, PPA's and more on...but no one has ever posted a definitive, longterm solution.

I've a HP with RealTek 3290 WiFi+Bluetooth adapter, but only WiFi work out-of-the-box.

Comment: Maybe true now .But someone could always make a working driver in the future :D

Answer (score 0):

I also was facing the same problem and I tried all the solution I could find and still could not solve it, most I was able to reach was that all the Bluetooth devices were showing but still I was unable to connect to any of them.

But I just today finally found something that works and is very easy to install, it is located on github [rtbth-dkms](https://github.com/loimu/rtbth-dkms).

To Install,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:blaze/rtbth-dkms
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtbth-dkms
```

and then follow the `Init` commands below, your BlueTooth will work now, in case of any problem leave a comment,  I will be happy to help you.

Usage

```
# Init
sudo modprobe rtbth
sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth
hcitool dev # check

# Switch off
sudo rfkill block bluetooth

# Switch on
sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth

# Shutdown
sudo pkill -2 rtbt
sudo rmmod rtbth
```